Pagination on Home Page - Want http://website.com/submissions/?page=2, not http://website.com/?page=2
I'm using the Pagy Gem for pagination. What i'm trying to do is render the partial in my Home page with the pagination (this is working how I want currently), but I want the 2 in 1,2,3 Next > to go to http://website.com/submissions/?page=2 not http://website.com/?page=2. I want this to go straight into Page 2 of my Submissions index, not Page 2 of the Home page.
Is there a way to add options for this? I tried looking into this and moving things around but cannot seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated!
Current Setup:
I'm rendering a partial into my index.html.erb in my Home folder.
<%= render "submissions/submissions", submission: @submission %>

This partial contains the code (the submissions items) I want to display plus the fast helper their documentation provides to output the pagination numbers below those submissions items:
<%== pagy_nav(@pagy) %>

application_controller.rb
include Pagy::Backend

application_helper.rb
include Pagy::Frontend

Wrapping collections with pagy in my index actions on submissions_controller.rb
def index 
 @pagy @submissions = pagy(Submission.all)
end

Routes.rb:
root to: "home#index"


Docs: "How To Customize the URL"

@engineersmnky Thanks for providing this! I'm still trying to understand. I've been looking into it but cannot seem to piece this together with my limited knowledge of Rails at the moment.

As per my opinion you will solve your problem by updating your route
do something like this in your routes.rb file
resources :submissions, only: [:index] do
end

This will generate the route you want but you need to adjust the .html.erb file from home folder to:
app/views/submissions/index.html.erb

and render your response accordingly

Hey! @Mirza Usman, thanks for giving some input here! I've done this but i'm not trying to change my root to root submissions#index, i'm wanting to keep it at root "home#index", render my pagination partial but make sure when you click Page 2 or Next it'll take you directly to page 2 of the submissions page (submissions?page=2) from Home.

Your question is not clear. It looks like you want to go to the submission page only if the page is 2, which would be very weird.
Assuming you mean to serve the pagination on home but you want to have all the links pointing to "/submissions", that would be as simple as:
@pagy, @records = pagy(collection, request_path: '/submissions')


